# Passing data to sub-controller for insert or update

Tags: angularjs

I have a main controller for my profile edit page, from where users can add their education, in a modal window. The modal has it's own controller. The user can add as many education items they want and they can modify the existing ones.

Now for my issue. I want the modal controller to take care of both adding a new item and updating an existing one. The difference is that on update, the controller should receive a fully populated `education` object, which it should update. I don't know how to pass this object from the main controller to the modal controller. I've seen some ways of passing data between controllers via services, but that seems too much of a hassle, and it doesn't make sense to me to use a service in this particular case.

My main controller creates modals like so:

```
vm.openEducation = function(){
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: "some.html",
        controller: "SomeController",
        controllerAs: "vm",
        size: 'lg'
    }).result.then(function (education) {
            vm.educations.push(education);
        });
}
```

And the child controller (which currently only supports insert, hence the empty init of `vm.education`):

```
function SomeController($scope){
    var vm = this;
    vm.education = {}; // or get from parent controller

    vm.save = function () {
        $scope.$close(vm.education);
    };

    vm.close = function () {
        $scope.$dismiss();
    }

    return vm;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$rootScope.$broadcast` to send data from the modal and then `$scope.$on` to receive that data anywhere else.

For example:

```
// in your modal
$rootScope.$broadcast('education:updated', yourDataObj)

// in your controller
$scope.$on('education:updated', function(e, data) { 
    console.log(data)
})
```

Note that the `$broadcast` will be picked up by anything that's listening for it, so if you have multiple controller instances you will get multiple `console.log` messages